# I got a written job offer for a graduate role in a big government company 3 weeks but have not heard since then

Tags: job-offer, contracts

I got the written job offer exactly 3 weeks ago in a government company, they said that they will come back with a contract offer but I have not heard anything from them since then.

I need to find out, because this means that I have to relocate and find accommodation. I'm thinking of sending an email asking them about what the situation is currently. Should I do that and is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a dupe - the linked question is about an earlier stage in the process. In this case the OP has had a written offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I'd say that it would be a good idea to follow up at this point - 3 weeks isn't an insanely long period of time, especially in government bureaucracies contracts can take a while to work their way through the machinery but it's starting to push it and I wouldn't like to leave it longer really. Send a polite e-mail inquiring as when you can expect a contract through, if you don't get a reply to that in a day or two I'd consider escalating with a phone call if you have a contact number.